# Python subprocess.call with timeout retry

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to re-run subprocess.call if it's timeout somehow.

```
subprocess.call('some command', timeout=600)
if timeout:
    subprocess.call('some command')
```

How do i do something like this?

Comment: why would you try to call it again immediately if it just *timed-out*?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I had this need too, when I need to contact a service which could take a few minutes to start up. Today i would have done it a bit differently - use a shorter timeout and add Delay before the next attempt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*subprocess.call* raises [[Python 3.Docs]: exception subprocess.TimeoutExpired](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.TimeoutExpired) when timeout is (given and) reached (just like *Popen.communicate*).

Here's a piece of code that keeps launching *NotePad* with a timeout of 3 seconds, until it runs 2 times, or user manually closes it:

> ```py
> >>> max_runs = 2
> >>> run = 0
> >>> while run < max_runs:
> ...     try:
> ...             subprocess.call("notepad", timeout=3)
> ...     except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
> ...             continue
> ...     else:
> ...             break
> ...     finally:
> ...             run += 1
> ...
> 0
> ```

Although this technically answers the question, I don't think it's a good idea to re-launch a process that didn't end, since there's a great chance that the consecutive runs will have the same outcome (will timeout). In that case, you'd have to use *Popen* and *communicate*, and if the process times out, kill it via *Popen.terminate*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic error handling to do catch the timeout exception:

```
try:
    subprocess.call('cmd', timeout=0)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Expired!')
    # subprocess.call('cmd')
```

The `except` block is only run if the specified error is raised. See [Python docs tutorial on exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html), specifically [error handling](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more information.